# Add an incremental query within a defined insert query

Tags: python, postgresql, logging, bots, telegram

i have the following incomplete function:

```
def logs(user_logs):

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(DB_CONNECTION_STRING)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO \"Logs\" (user_id, telegram_nickname, command) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);", user_logs,)
    conn.commit()
    return None

except Exception as e:
    return e
```

i want to add an incremental column after "command", called "usage". The goal is to track the usage of commands from a telegram bot.
Example: command>/start usage>1  if another user type /start, the usage number should increment by 1, and so on.

Comment: I've added "  .split(" ")[0]  " next to logs function in the main file(not the one listed there) to resolve the input problem.

Comment: Post your actual code. It wastes other's time to consider and answer your question... which is what exactly? You mention and incremental column, then ask a question about the input commands, then state in a comment that you have solved the input problem already. Please post a coherent question.

Comment: you're right, i've edited my question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logging function groups commands by userid but you seem to want an overall count for all users? If that is the case it makes little sense to add a "usage" column to the log table.

You could use a separate table to keep usage counts per command, but it's far easier to do nothing at all. Keep the current log table then get the count using SQL:

```
select count(*) from logs where command = '/start'
```

then you can find the current count for any command.

This is more flexible too; if you wanted the count for a single user then you could augment the WHERE clause to filter by userid. Grouping is also possible using `GROUP BY`.

---

**Original answer**

Can't you just pass the first part of the command string to the log function?

```
if text.startswith('/'):
    command = text.split()[0]
    logs(user_id, telegram_nickname, command)
    if command == '/start':
    etc...etc..
```

Here [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is used to grab the first part of the command for logging.

Comment: I have another function in the main file to take user id, telegram nickname and commands and pass it to the logs functions in the OP, and yes, i've resolved this part by using str.split() =) thanks

Comment: You're absolutely right. There was a big problem behind my question, i wanted to filter commands usage by user_id, this lead to some problems because i will have multiple rows with the same command but different "usage". Your simple SELECT query will definitely resolve my problem leaving the code as it is right now! Thanks a lot!!!!